# With optional chaining receiving TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am receiving the error:

```
instrument.js:110 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at useScenariosGraphql.tsx:128
    at _o (react-dom.production.min.js:231)
    at Du (react-dom.production.min.js:278)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at ql (react-dom.production.min.js:130)
    at Fu (react-dom.production.min.js:277)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:277
    at A (scheduler.production.min.js:17)
    at MessagePort.x.port1.onmessage (scheduler.production.min.js:14)
```

This is occurring here:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let message: string | undefined;
    const error = createError ?? updateError;
    if (error) {
      if (
        // @ts-ignore
        error.graphQLErrors?.[0].data?.messages?.[0] // <---- ERROR HERE Line 128
      )
        // @ts-ignore
        message = error.graphQLErrors?.[0].data?.messages?.[0];
      if (error?.message.includes('same organization as the scenario'))
        message =
          'To create a new scenario, all target areas must be in the same organization as that scenario. You can fix this in the data tab at the top.';
      // @ts-ignore
      if (typeof error?.graphQLErrors?.[0].data?.errors?.[1]?.data?.messages?.[0] === 'string')
        // @ts-ignore
        message = error?.graphQLErrors?.[0].data?.errors?.[1]?.data?.messages?.[0];
      if (!message) {
        message = `Something went wrong with the network request`;
        console.log(error.message);
      }

      addToast(message, 10000);
    }
  }, [addToast, createError, updateError]);
```

`@ts-ignore` is because the GraphQL Error type does not have a data property, but the object returned sometimes does from the GrahphQL Backend.

Either way, if it is there or it isn't, why am I getting cannot read `data` of undefined when I'm using optional chaining? Shouldn't it resolve to undefined when it doesn't find index `0` of the `graphQLErrors` array?

We know the variable `error` exists because of the if statement. So now I'm checking `error.graphQLErrors[0]` which is `undefined`... but that's why I'm using optional chaining instead of the verbose:

```
  if (
    error.graphQLErrors[0] &&
    error.graphQLErrors[0].data &&
    error.graphQLErrors[0].data.messages[0]
  )
```

But it isn't working as intended... help please.

---

Edit

Okay I see I need a `?` after the index as well. Is the first question mark saying if the index actually exists and the second one if the value at that index is not nullish in `variable?.[0]?`

Comment: add a `?` after the first `[0]` and remove the `.` from before both the indexers --> `error.graphQLErrors?[0]?.data?.messages?[0]`

Comment: @phuzi `.` before indexer actually **is** required https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Syntax

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ahh, sorry. Thinking of C# where they are not required!

Comment: @phuzi yes a bit annoying, but I guess needed to differentiate with ternary operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the optional chaining `?` operator when accessing the `graphQLErrors` array:

```
error.graphQLErrors?.[0].data?.messages?.[0]
```

Change to:

```
error.graphQLErrors?.[0]?.data?.messages?.[0]
```